# Insert into a vector in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, vector, insert

I am trying to insert into this Vector (mCards) in alphabetical order. I can't use sort - it must be inserted in alphabetical order! Right now, I'm inserting in reverse. I can't figure out how to get this to insert in correct alphabetical order!

```
void Rolodex::Add(Card& card)
    {
        vector<Card>::iterator temp;
    
        if (mCards.size() != 0)
        {
            for(vector<Card>::iterator it = mCards.begin(); it != mCards.end(); ++it)
            {
                Card& currentCard = *it;
                temp = it;
               int compareResult = currentCard.GetLastName().compare(card.GetLastName());
                if (compareResult <= 0)
                {
                    mIteratorNumber = it - mCards.begin();
                    mCards.insert(temp, card); 
                    return;
                }
    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mCards.push_back(card);
            for(vector<Card>::iterator it = mCards.begin(); it != mCards.end(); ++it)
            {
                mIteratorNumber = it - mCards.begin();  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use sort?

Comment: It must be "inserted" into the alphabetical position. This is for a homework assignment.

Comment: Consider `std::map<std::string, Card>`, where the key is the name of the card.

Comment: Ah yes, homework assignments, teaching you how to write bad code and you probably have to pay for the privilege!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/

Answer (score 0):

If you wants a sorted container, you may instead look at [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or their multi variant if you may have duplicated values.

To insert into a sorted vector, the right way to do it is to use [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)

```
myCards.insert( std::upper_bound( begin(myCards), end(myCards), card), card );
```

If the card do not have a valid `operator<`, use a predicate like this

```
auto it = std::upper_bound( begin(myCards), end(myCards), card,
                            [] ( Card const & a, Card const & b ) {
                                return a.GetLastName().compare(b.GetLastName()) < 0;
                            } );
myCards.insert( it, card );
```